# Como reproduzir erros no android studio e por onde começar a investigação

Tags: android

estou tentando reproduzir esse erro abaixo no apk mas impossível saber por onde começar, vejam só:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:101)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1972)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelContent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1262)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.openPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1104)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUpPanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1469)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onKeyUp(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:919)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:913)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:241)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2185)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4565)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4130)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4264)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4321)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4130)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4130)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4184)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4297)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4457)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2263)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1909)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1900)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2240)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 43 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010084 a=3}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3411)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:1101)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:152)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:148)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView.<init>(ExpandedMenuView.java:52)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView.<init>(ExpandedMenuView.java:48)
... 46 more
```

Não sei nem por onde começar. Alguém pode me dar algumas dicas? Obrigado

Comment: Posta o XML dessa classe que esta tendo o erro Higor, provavelmente você está colocando um *R.drawable.nome* em local errado

Comment: Leonardo, não sei qual é a classe porque o app é enorme e tem muitas classes... Esse é um dos problemas... A gente tem que corrigir bugs capturados pelo pelo google analytics...